# Using zIndexOffset for markerCluster

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer

In my project several layers of clustered data are shown. Layering should be consistent, i.e. if the user moves a layer up, it's markers and marker groups should always move above other layers markers and marker groups.

When building regular L.marker layers, I can pass a marker a zIndexOffset to control what z-index layers are layered at. This works nicely and also works for L.marker's that were not included in a marker group.

Is there a way to set a zIndexOffset for cluster groups?

as requested:

```
    success: function(data,text,xhr) {
                var newMarkerList = [];
                $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
                      var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(data.geometry.coordinates[1],
                                                     data.geometry.coordinates[0]),
                                  { icon:     L.icon({iconUrl: baseUrl+"/webcommon/images/"+data.properties.icon, 
                                                      iconSize: [24,24]})
                                  }
                      );
                      popupContent = createContentFromFeature(data);  

                      marker.bindPopup(popupContent,{
                         autoPan:      true
                        ,closeButton:  true
                        ,autoClose:    true
                        ,closeOnClick: false});

                      newMarkerList.push(marker);
                });
                currentLayer.addLayers(newMarkerList); 
             }
```

coordinates and icon come from database via ajax, popupContent is a div which is filled by createContentFromFeature().

Comment: Depending on how you're creating the marker clusters you might be able to use the leaflet [`zIndex`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-pane) option, or the [`pane`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-pane) option. Can you include some of your code?

Comment: solved it with setZIndexOffset() on the markers. this works fine for the unclustered Icons but no for the Cluster Icons. but is's better than nothing. ;)